# CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation stopped working under iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, cloudkit

I have an app that supports iOS 8 and higher. I have been using `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation` to get a list of users for sharing purposes. This code works just fine under iOS 8 and iOS 9. But under iOS 10, the completion block returns no error but it also returns no results, even when there are some.

I've also noted the following message in the console:

> <Error>: Got a user discovery progress callback with no record id: { }

This appears between the time the the operation is started and the completion block is called.

Here is the relevant code:

```
CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation *op = [[CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation alloc] init];
op.discoverAllContactsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray <CKDiscoveredUserInfo *> *userInfos, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get all app users: %@", error);
    } else {
        // process the found users
    }
};
[container addOperation:op];
```

I know that `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation` is deprecated as of iOS 10 and has been replaced by `CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation`. But since my app supports back to iOS 8, there shouldn't be any reason why I can't use the same code even under iOS 10. In fact, I still use several other deprecated (as of iOS 10) CloudKit classes and this is the only one giving me a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it seems that `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation` simply doesn't work as it should under iOS 10. This is probably a bug in iOS 10 and a bug will be filed with Apple. But I have users complaining now and a work around is needed now.

The simplest solution is to use the new operation when available and use the old one when not.

This resulted in the following basic code:

```
if ([CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation class]) {
    // Use the newer operation
    CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation *op = [[CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray array];
    op.userIdentityDiscoveredBlock = ^(CKUserIdentity *identity) {
        if (identity.hasiCloudAccount) {
            DatabaseShareUser *user = [[DatabaseShareUser alloc] init];
            user.recordId = identity.userRecordID;
            user.username = [NSPersonNameComponentsFormatter localizedStringFromPersonNameComponents:identity.nameComponents style:NSPersonNameComponentsFormatterStyleDefault options:0];
            [users addObject:user];
        }
    };
    op.discoverAllUserIdentitiesCompletionBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to get app users: %@", error);

            completion(nil);
        } else {
            completion([users copy]);
        }
    };

    [container addOperation:op];
} else {
    // Use the old operation
    CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation *op = [[CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation alloc] init];
    op.discoverAllContactsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray <CKDiscoveredUserInfo *> *userInfos, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to get app users: %@", error);

            completion(nil);
        } else {
            NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (CKDiscoveredUserInfo *userInfo in userInfos) {
                DatabaseShareUser *user = [[DatabaseShareUser alloc] init];
                user.recordId = userInfo.userRecordID;
                user.username = userInfo.displayName;
                [res addObject:user];
            }

            completion([res copy]);
        }
    };
    [container addOperation:op];
}
```

`DatabaseShareUser` is a simple app class that stores the `CKRecordID` and display name of each user.

`completion` is a completion block used by the method this code is in.

Comment: Wondering if Apple has indicated any progress on fixing this bug. Thank you.

Comment: @AnthonyC Not that I've heard. Since there is a reasonable workaround I'm not worried about it.